# Is there a way to remove the else in this code?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to remove the else in this code?

```rust
if let Err(err) = something.command(name).await {
    if let CustomEnum::NotFound(_) = err {
    } else {
        return Err(err);
    }
}
```

If it's not found is ok for me, I wanna return Err in each other case of CustomEnum.

Comment: `if !matches(err, CustomEnum::NotFound(_))`, perhaps? It is a little clunky, but this could be fixed by having a method like `err.is_not_found()` you could call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `matches!` or a match statement:

```rs
if let Err(err) = something.command(name).await {
    if !matches!(err, CustomEnum::NotFound(_)) {
        return Err(err);
    }
}
```

```rs
if let Err(err) = something.command(name).await {
    match err {
        CustomEnum::NotFound(_) => (),
        _ => return Err(err),
    }
}
```